# How to bind a listbox to a collection within a complex type located within my ViewModel?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

My view model currently contains a "SelectedClient" property which refers to the selected "Client" object in a datagrid.  This selected client property contains a property titled "OfficeLocations" which is essentially just a list of "OfficeLocation" objects.

I am trying to bind a listbox to the SelectedClients.OfficeLocations property like so:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedClient.OfficeLocations}" />
```

But for some reason the ListBox always shows up blank.  Once again, in debug mode when I view the SelectedClient.OfficeLocations property, it does in fact contain data.

I've also tried something like:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedClient, Path=OfficeLocations}" />
```

To no avail.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated..Thanks!

Comment: The `SelectedClient` property setter does raise the `PropertyChanged` event on your viewmodel, right?

Comment: This probably could have easily been solved by turning up the databinding log:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/MF8i5.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, so it turns out that I was trying to do this binding with a DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate which overrides my DataContext to SelectedItem already...meaning changing my binding to look like:

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding OfficeLocations, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

Fixed the issue!